# Is Python/ArcPy capable of delimiting strings with commas into different fields, and running a calculation based on those separate columns

Tags: python, arcpy, python-script-tool

Using ArcGIS ArcMap 10.6:

I have a text field in an attribute table that has comma separated values (example: 12,24, 64, 87,29). For this example, I will name this field `VALUES`. Please note that `VALUES` includes data collected from field work so the spacing between commas will be varied.

My current workflow is as followed:

1. Export the `ID` and `VALUES` fields in the attribute table into a .csv file using Table to Table in ArcMap 10.6
2. Open the .csv in Excel and run the 'text to columns' function under the Data ribbon
3. Separate the `VALUES` field into multiple columns based on commas
4. Run the calculation:
5. Copy `Column I` values and `ID` columns into a new .csv file
6. Save and close the new .csv file and join the shapefile to the new .csv file based on `ID`
7. Export the newly joined shapefile into a new file and delete the duplicate `ID` field in the new shapefile

I am wondering if there is a way to automate this Python/ArcPy so I can create a custom script tool to do this without leaving the ArcGIS environment.

**Is there a way to separate values in a text field based on commas into different columns, run the above calculation, and have the values from that calculation entered in a new field named** `VALUES_CALCULATED`?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I think you should look into AddField and UpdateCursor.  I don't see any need to use CSV in this workflow.

Comment: Yes, string.split(',') will break it up, in a list comprehension to convert strings to integer/float will ignore spaces [float( x ) for x in ValuesFromRow] where ValuesFromRow is either a row in an update cursor or a field in an advanced field calculation. Do you have any experience with python? If so can you share your existing code so we can see where you're up to if not you could use field calculator to simplify but it's going to be onerous, fortunately you can save field calculator expressions for reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get you started, use da.UpdateCursor for the calculation:

```
import arcpy, math
fc = r"X:\testdata.shp" #Change to match your feature class
fields = ['VALUES','Calcvals'] #Change to match your field names

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            newval=math.sqrt(sum(list(map(lambda x: float(x)**2, row[0].replace(' ','').split(',')))))
            row[1]=newval
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        except ValueError: #For example if there are no values in VALUES column
            pass
```

This is whats happening:

```
a = '12,24, 64.5, 87,29'

a = a.replace(' ','')
#'12,24,64.5,87,29'

a = a.split(',')
#['12', '24', '64.5', '87', '29']

a = list(map(lambda x: float(x)**2, a))
#[20736.0, 331776.0, 17307680.0625, 57289761.0, 707281.0]

a = round(math.sqrt(sum(a)), 2)
#115.28
```